# RxJava, execute code in the observer thread before chaining two observables

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using RxJava and RxAndroid, and I want to combine two observables but in between I need to update the UI, so I must execute code in the main thread before *reaching* the subscriber.

One solution, instead of flatmapping (is that an accepted term?) two observables, would be to call the next observable in the subscriber just after updating the UI, but I feel that there should be a more elegant solution like:

```
myObservable
    .map(new Func1<Object, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Object object) {
            /* do stuff on the main thread */
            return object;
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<Object, Observable<OtherObject>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<OtherObject> call(Object o) {
            return new MyOtherObservable(o);
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Of course, probably map is not the operator I need to use here. So, is there an operator or a better way to achieve this? Or am I missing the point about how observables should work?

Answer (score 4):

Rxjava has a doOnNext operator which is what you're looking for.

Comment: Is that called on the observer thread? The documentation states that it doesn't run on a particular scheduler.

Comment: You'll have to use observeOn and specify the scheduler

Comment: Thanks, so to be sure, this means that everything I run on the doOnNext will run in the same thread as the subscriber.

Comment: Just checked, doOnNext is being called in another thread, while the subscriber is being called in the main one (using observeOn to the main thread).

Comment: ObserveOn should ne called before doOnNext